# Cannot change lockscreen shortcuts on Samsung Galaxy S III, Android 4.3 JellyBean

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-s-3, lock-screens, 4.3-jelly-bean

I have Samsung I9300 Galaxy S III running on Android 4.3 JellyBean. I am unable to find a way to change the shortcuts on the lock screen.

Here is the available settings:

[image]

[image]

I tried all the settings, but it doesn't work.

Could you guide me through how I can achieve this?

Comment: More details needed and question is not clear.

Comment: @MANI that's for sure, but I've made a guess at it being the lock screen short cuts that Samsung have on the rightmost lockscreen. It is disabled by default, and the method for navigating the options on Samsung devices is..... confusing at the best of times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable lockscreen widgets, to allow the shortcuts to be shown.

- Go to `Settings > My device > Lock Screen` and tick the box "**Multiple widgets**"

The actual layout can change from device to device slightly, but below will give you a rough guide to how to find them.

[image]

- Now click on "**Lock screen widgets** and turn on the button "**Favourite apps or camera**" on.
- Now click on the actual option (by this I mean click the ***text***, not the button) "**Favourite apps or camera** and select "**Favourite apps**" and hit save.

[image]
<sub>(source: [laptopmag.com](http://blog.laptopmag.com/wpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/lock-screen-favorite-apps-or-camera.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Thank you. I did everything that you said.
but the problem is that I don't have the shortcuts on the menu at all. I think. you think the shortcuts switch in not avtive in my mobile. but I don't have that option at all.

Comment: @givarawan What version of Android are you on? That could be the issue. I definitely have this option on 4.3 and 4.4.2 on the S4.. I don't have an S3 to hand here, but I'll look around in a bit.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy s3 GT i 9300 version 4.3

Comment: @givarawan that's very odd, it is possible the network carrier locked these down (I know Orange used to do it) but I have the option here on a friend's S3 matching my own... What are the options under the 'Lockscreen widgets' option?

Comment: @givarawan sorry the second one didn't load in for some reason. All I can see is that you don't have the option, but I don't know WHY it has been disabled, or isn't available. [This article](http://www.knowyourmobile.com/samsung/17983/how-give-your-samsung-galaxy-s3s-lockscreen-personal-touch) suggests that you can add a few shortcuts to the screen also, but you don't have the "shortcuts" option at all. I'll have to keep digging to find you an answer.